# What compiler do I use for VSCode FreeRTOS Embedded Programming? Should I see GNU in the list?

Tags: visual-studio-code, embedded, vscode-extensions, freertos, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I am using a Mac and VSCode and have installed the [GNU embedded GNU Arm Embedded toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain). When I right click on CMakeLists.txt and select Build All Projects it asks me to select a compiler. Should I see the GNU one in the list?

[image]

I expect [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) changes will be necessary, at least for any given project, but it would be good to see it as a selectable option for any project.

My ArmGNUToolchain is here:

```
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/12.2.mpacbti-rel1/arm-none-eabi
```